# C# HttpWebRequest - How to disgtinguish between HTML and XML pages without downloading?

Tags: c#, html, xml, httpwebrequest, xmlreader

I need to be able to tell if a link (URL) points to an XML file (RSS feed), or a regular HTML file just by looking at the headers, or something similiar (without downloading it)

Any good advice for me there ? :)

Thanks!
Roey

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just do a HEAD request instead of a full POST/GET

That will get you the headers for that page which should include the content type.
From that you should be able to distinguish if its text/html or xml

Theres a good example [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153451/c-how-to-check-if-system-net-webclient-downloaddata-is-downloading-a-binary-fi)

Comment: +1 the perfect answer and the exact reason for the existence of the HEAD request

Comment: Just a minor reminder some servers do not support HEAD, so do not forget to fall back to GET/POST when it fails.

Comment: I count one "could" and two "should". ;]

Comment: indeed... it does make the assumption that the webserver in question supports HTTP HEAD Requests & that the content mimetypes are being set correctly if at all, but I suppose those scenarios would be the exception to the rule.

Answer (score 5):

Following up on Eoin Campbell's response, here's a code snippet that should do exactly that using the `System.Net` functionality:

```
using (var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(
    "http://tempuri.org/pathToFile"))
{
    request.Method = "HEAD";

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        switch (response.ContentType)
        {
            case "text/xml":
                // ...
                break;
            case "text/html":
                // ...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that the web server publishes the content (MIME) type and does so correctly. But since you stated that want a bandwidth-efficient way of doing this, I assume you don't want to download all the markup and analyse that! To be honest, the content type is usually set correctly in any case.

Comment: You can just use response.ContentType;

Comment: This answers exactly half the question. There are some tricky content-types out there, like:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#application-xhtml-xml

Comment: @bzlm: Yeah, but do they really get used? We're only talking about HTML and XML types here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Content-Type` header, and to save bandwidth you can force web server to serve you a specified part of a document. If the server includes `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header in its response, you can use `Range: bytes=0-10` to download first ten bytes only (or even try not to download anything).

Also research `HEAD` verb instead of `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the headers in your HttpWebResponse object. The Content-Type header should read text/xml for an XML/RSS document and text/html for a standard web page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find out what file type it is just from looking at the URL.

I suggest you try to check the MIME-type of the document you request, or read the first line and hope the author has put in a Doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this impossible.  This is because it is possible (though unhelpful) to serve either HTML or XML files as application/octet-stream.  Also, as noted by others, there are multiple valid XML mime types.  However, a HEAD request then content type check could work sometimes:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
req.Method = "HEAD";
String contentType = resp.ContentType;

if(contentType == "text/xml")
  getXML(url);
else if(contentType == "text/html")
  getHTML(url);
```

But if you're going to process it somehow either way, you can do:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
String contentType = resp.ContentType;

if(contentType == "text/xml")
  processXML(resp.GetResponseStream());
else if(contentType == "text/html")
  processHTML(resp.GetResponseStream());
else
  // process error condition
```

Keep in mind, files are downloaded on an as-needed basis.  So just asking for the response object does not cause the whole file to be downloaded.

Answer (score -3):

just read it in a "text" reader. 
then decide which is best by, for example, looking for some tags  comes to mind ;)
then chuck it in your actual reader.

or is that too simple?

Comment: He specifically said he wanted to know before downloading the whole file.