# Calculate the total size of all files to download

Tags: c#

VS 2008 SP1

I am creating a updater that my application will, when started will fetch updated files from a web server.

I am wonder how I can get the total size of the files to download?

I need this information as I am using a progress bar to monitor the amount that is currently downloading, and need to set the total as the max value of the progress bar.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does your updater work out which files to download? So long as you can get a list of files to download and their sizes before you start downloading anything, you've just got to sum the sizes...

The only problem I could see is if you download some files and then (after updating) find you need to download more.

Comment: Hello. I have decided to use the webclient it has events for downloadprogress and the event arguments give the size of the file. That is all very well. But I am looking to download all the files one after the other and take the progress of the total size and the amount that has already downloaded.

Comment: But how do you know which files to download to start with? Wherever you get that information from, make it give you file sizes too.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sum over a number of files, loop and sum; then the question becomes how to get the size of a single file without downloading it. Here, the "HEAD" verb may help. You mention `WebClient`; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153451#156750) is an example of subclassing `WebClient` to get just the headers.

Of course, it isn't guaranteed that you'll get a content-length header...