# Copy file from one domain to another

Tags: c#

I have two different websites running on two different servers with URL say `http://192.168.0.102:1004` and `http://192.168.0.122:1005`.

Now i am trying to copy a image file from `http://192.168.0.102:1004` to `http://192.168.0.122:1005` using following code

```
if (File.Exists("http://192.168.0.122:1005/Assets/Images/Stores/14/14_Logo.png"))
{
    File.Copy("http://192.168.0.122:1005/Assets/Images/Stores/14/14_Logo.png", "http://192.168.0.102:1004/Assets/Images/Stores/14/14_Logo.png", true);
}
```

But `If` condition always return me `false`. However if i copy this URL in browser, it render me `desired image` on page.

If file exists, i need to copy it from source domain to target domain.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: How do i copy the file from that domain to target domain ??

Comment: You can't use System.IO.File methods with urls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the File object for these kinds of checks.

Please see the answer on: [can I check if a file exists at a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979915/can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-at-a-url)

TL;DR
You should check if the server returns a 200 (OK) using the `HttpWebRequest` object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this does not answer my question fully. How do i copy image from source domain to target domain then?

Comment: @RajeevKumar Download the image and save to disk

Comment: You should look at various protocols. You can't simply use HTTP like that. You need to set up a server (with authentication) and decide exactly how to send files (with POST or PUT). SFTP is probably a more sensible protocol.