# Check Azure CDN if image exists

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cdn

Is there any way, with any of the .Net Azure libraries to check if a resource exists on the CDN. I can check if a blob exists but haven't come across anything that will check if it also exists on the CDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that your BLOB URL is :

```
http://foo.blob.core.windows.net/cdn/test.png
```

and that your CDN endpoint is `bar.vo.msecnd.net`

Just do an HTTP HEAD request on `http://bar.vo.msecnd.net/cdn/test.png` to see if the file exists.

To paraphrase the code submitted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1980006/82136)

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://bar.vo.msecnd.net/cdn/test.png");
request.Method = "HEAD";


try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    /* do something here */
}
finally
{
    // Don't forget to close your response.
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: But won't this lead to the CDN fetching the image ?

Comment: No, because it's HEAD not GET, ao it's not fethcing the img respone body