# Download file from multiple URLs

Tags: c#, url, unity-game-engine, download

I need to download the file from URL_1. If the file is not available (returns 404), on URL_1, script has to try to download the file from URL_2.

Now I'm using `HttpWebRequest`, but it takes too long to check the availability of my file.

```
private bool IsPageExists(string url)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I check if a file exists at a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979915/can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-at-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'm using HttpWebRequest, but it takes too long to check the
>   availability of my file

That's because you are not doing that in another `Thread` so it will like block the main Thread until the request is done. Using `HttpWebRequest` requires threading and a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540#41333540) to notify the main thread when you are done.

You should use Unity's `WWW` or `UnityWebRequest` to make that request in a coroutine. These two API will make the question with Thread in the background. You just wait for it to finish with a coroutine. You can organize multiple requests with the help of `Action`.

A simple **re-usable** download function that returns true on success:

```
IEnumerator getRequest(string uri, Action<bool> success)
{
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    //Check if there is an error
    if (uwr.isError || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uwr.error))
    {
        success(false);
    }
    else
    {
        success(true);
        //Store downloaded data to the global variable
        downloadedData = uwr.downloadHandler.data;
    }
}
```

To make requests in order(3 requests):

```
IEnumerator downloadMultipleFile()
{
    bool success = false;

    //Download first file
    yield return getRequest(url1, (status) => { success = status; });

    //Check if download was successful
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("File downloaded from the first url");
        //Use downloadedData here

        //Exit
        yield break;
    }
    Debug.Log("Error downloading from first url");

    //Download second file
    yield return getRequest(url2, (status) => { success = status; });

    //Check if download was successful
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("File downloaded from the second url");
        //Use downloadedData here

        //Exit
        yield break;
    }
    Debug.Log("Error downloading from second url");

    //Download third file
    yield return getRequest(url3, (status) => { success = status; });

    //Check if download was successful
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("File downloaded from the second url");
        //Use downloadedData here

        //Exit
        yield break;
    }
    Debug.Log("Error downloading from third url");
}
```

Usage:

```
string url1 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/38265/flower-blossom-bloom-winter-38265.jpeg";
string url2 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/404313/pexels-photo-404313.jpeg";
string url3 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/65891/prairie-dog-rodent-animals-cynomys-65891.jpeg";

byte[] downloadedData;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(downloadMultipleFile());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [**WWW**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class:

```
IEnumerator WWWClass()
    {
        string url1 = "xyz.com";
        string url2 = "xyzzz.com";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            //sucess
        }
        else {
            //unscuess
            www = new WWW(url2);
            yield return www;
            if (www.error == null)
            {
                //sucess
            }
            else {
                //unscuess
            }
        }
    }
```

if error is null then resource found else it is error try another url.