# Does the WebClient class support changing the HTTP method to HEAD?

Tags: .net-3.5, webclient

Does the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh(v=VS.90).aspx) support changing the method to HEAD?

I like the simplicity of using this class but if it's not that flexible then I will simply switch over to using the full-fledged HttpWebRequest and Response classes.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153451/c-how-to-check-if-system-net-webclient-downloaddata-is-downloading-a-binary-fi/156750#156750) shows how you can do it with subclassing.

Comment: @Matthew, I saw the subclassing thing in the MSDN docs but was hoping there was another way without created a new data type (I mean a way that's not reflection either :). Why not throw your answer down below because it's a good contender by what I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc Gravell [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153451/c-how-to-check-if-system-net-webclient-downloaddata-is-downloading-a-binary-fi/156750#156750) a solution to a similar problem, using a subclass.

Comment: Although I've chosen against using this in my program, it seems the most correct answer all things considered, so am accepting it as such. Thanks.