# Politely checking to see if a file exists before downloading

Tags: vb.net, webclient, system.net, system.net.webexception

I'm trying to download files using the Net.WebClient call to DownloadFile

```
Using client As New Net.WebClient()   
  Try
    client.DownloadFile(PDFURL, FullPDFFilePath)
```

I then catch the exception and check the message for 403, 404, or 500 errors (the most common type for the system we are calling into.

```
 Catch ex as exception
   If exceptionMessage.Contains("(403)") Then 'Forbidden
     LogInformation("403 returned on download for " + CRPOrderNum, "DownloadLabels")

   ElseIf exceptionMessage.Contains("(404)") Then 'Not Found
     LogInformation("404 returned on download for " + CRPOrderNum, "DownloadLabels")

   else
     'blah blah
   end if
 finally
 end try
```

Is there a polite way I can ask for the file instead of calling DownloadFile, and handling the exception ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The "polite" way would be to send a HEAD request. Unfortunately WebClient doesn't support this natively so you'd either have to [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153451/c-how-to-check-if-system-net-webclient-downloaddata-is-downloading-a-binary-fi) or use HttpWebRequest instead.