# How to check if a url is valid or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, uri

I am trying to filter out invalid url from valid ones using .NET.

I am using [Uri.TryCreate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131573.aspx) method for this.

It has the following syntax

```
public static bool TryCreate(Uri baseUri,string relativeUri,out Uri result)
```

Now I am doing this....

```
Uri uri = null;

var domainList = new List<string>();
domainList.Add("asas");
domainList.Add("www.stackoverflow.com");
domainList.Add("www.codera.org");
domainList.Add("www.joker.testtest");
domainList.Add("about.me");
domainList.Add("www.ma.tt");

var correctList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in domainList)
{
    if(Uri.TryCreate(item, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
    {    
        correctList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I am trying the above code I expect it to remove `asas` and `www.joker.testtest` from the list, but it doesnt.

Can some one help me out on this.

Update :
just tried out with `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` this too did'nt help.

**More Update**

List of Valid uri

- http://www.ggogle.com
- www.abc.com
- www.aa.org
- www.aas.co
- www.hhh.net
- www.ma.tt

List of invalid uri

- asas
- as#@SAd
- this.not.valid
- www.asa.toptoptop

Comment: http://joshua-smith.net/articles/view-article/3/Check-if-a-URL-is-valid-with-C

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid

Comment: What is your definition of a valid URI? All of your examples _are_ valid URIs, though not all are real _domains_.

Comment: Maybe you could check via `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`, (oooops missed the update)

Comment: my guess he means the URI woyuldn't end with testtest 
so you will need to catch all uri endings

Comment: @Oded `asas` and `www.joker.testtest` are not valid from the list, I want to remove them. Non real domains are a okay.

Comment: @V4Vendetta - The OP added an update that he has tried that.

Comment: What do you mean by "not valid"? They are, as far as the URI specification is concerned, valid. What you are looking for is something else - those are all syntactically valid URIs.

Comment: Are you able to perform pings from this tool or is this offline only?

Comment: You need to define "Invalid". If "Invalid" means that URI does not exists then my solution will work. if "Invalid" means "Not Well Formed" the O.D. solution will suffice. otherwise, you need to define "Invalid"!

Comment: you still need to be more precise. from your point of view, what's the difference between `www.ma.tt` and `www.asa.toptoptop`? is `www.asa.topt` "Invalid"??

Comment: @MBZ .tt is a `valid` top level domain, while `.toptoptop` is not

Comment: `MUSEUM` is a valid top-level domain as well. so something like `www.asa.MUSEUM" is valid? check the tlds here: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what exactly URL (or URI, the difference is not significant here) is. For example, `http://stackoverflow.com` is a valid absolute URL. On the other hand, `stackoverflow.com` is technically a valid relative URL, but it would refer to the file named `stackoverflow.com` in the current directory, not the website with that name. But `stackoverflow.com` is a registered *domain name*.

If you want to check whether a domain name is valid, you need to define what exactly do you mean by “valid”:

1. Is it a valid domain name? Check whether the string consists of parts separated by dots, each part can contain letters, numbers and a hyphen (`-`). For example, `asas` and `this.not.valid` are both valid domain names.
2. Could it be an Internet domain name? Domain names on the Internet (as opposed to intranet) are specific in that they always have a TLD (top-level domain). So, `asas` certainly isn't an Internet domain name, but `this.not.valid` could be.
3. Is it a domain name under existing TLD? You can download [the list of all TLDs](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) and check against that. For example, `this.not.valid` wouldn't be considered valid under this rule, but `thisisnotvalid.com` would.
4. Is it a registered domain name?
5. Does the domain name resolve to an IP address? A domain name could be registered, but it still may not have an IP address in its DNS record.
6. Does the computer the domain name points to respond to requests? The requests that make the most sense are a simple HTTP request (e.g. trying to access `http://domaininquestion/`) or ping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

public static bool [IsWellFormedUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx)(
    string uriString,
    UriKind uriKind
)

Or Alternativly you can do this using RegExp like :

```
^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$
```

Take alook at this [list](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20)

Comment: tried after reading from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9356511/1182982, doesnt work either

Comment: They _are_ well formed. And as the OP added to the question, it did not work for his needs.

Comment: @Yasser Then you would have to make a request and test if its success or 404 error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that none of the urls you have added here will classify as Absolute URLs. For that you have to prefix the protocol of the URL to it.

You can test and find out that

www.stackoverflow.com - Relative URL
http://www.stackoverflow.com - Absolute URL
//www.stackoverflow.com - Absolute URL ( No surprise here. [Refer RFC 3986: "Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax", Section 4.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) )

The point is that you have to prefix at least `//` to show that its an absolute URL.

So, in a nutshell, since all your URLs are relative URLs, it passes all your tests.

Comment: This explains what is wrong with the code in the question, but it doesn't help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

All your examples are valid,
some are absolute URLs some are relative, thats why none are getting removed.

Else for each Uri, you might try and construct a `HttpWebRequest` class
and then check for correct responses.

Comment: `asas` and `www.joker.testtest` are not valid from the list

Comment: Technically, this is correct. But saying that `www.stackoverflow.com` is a valid relative URL is not the right way to look at it, because that would represent file named `www.stackoverflow.com` in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

After checking other's answer I am aware that you are not looking for existence of domain and ping back you need to test them based on your GRAMMER... or Syntax of domain name right?

For that you need to rely on regex test only... and make proper rule to eveluate the domain name and if they fail exclude them from the list.

You can [adopt](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url) these patterns and modify one to suite your need and then test them with every element in the list.

Answer (score -2):

all of your `URI`s are Well-Formatted `URI`s so `TryCreate` and `IsWellFormedUriString` will not work in your case.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153451/c-how-to-check-if-system-net-webclient-downloaddata-is-downloading-a-binary-f#156750), the solutions is trying to open the URI:

```
using(var client = new MyClient()) {
    client.HeadOnly = true;
    // fine, no content downloaded
    string s1 = client.DownloadString("www.stackoverflow.com");
    // throws 404
    string s2 = client.DownloadString("www.joker.testtest");
}
```

Comment: whats `MyClient` here ??